# lapply to multivariate function?

Tags: r

I have a Data Frame that contains, between other things, the following fields: userX, Time1, Time2, Time3. The number of observations is 2000.

I have a function that has as inputs userX, Time1, Time2, Time3 and return a data frame with 1 observation and 19 variables.

I want to apply that function to all the observations of the first data frame to make a new data frame with 2000 observations and 19 variables.

I thought about using lapply, but if I understand correctly, it only takes one variable.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

This is the code I have right now:

```
            # Make Data Frame for video actions between given times for user X 
    DataVideoActionT <- function (userX, Time1, Time2, Time3){
      #Get data for user X
      videoActionsX<-subset(videoLectureActions, username==userX)
      #Time1 = before first attempt
      videoActionsX_T1<-subset(videoActionsX, eventTimestamp<Time1)
      #Time2 = before best attemp
      videoActionsX_T2<-subset(videoActionsX, eventTimestamp<Time2 & eventTimestamp>Time1)
      #Time3= before last attemp
      videoActionsX_T3<-subset(videoActionsX, eventTimestamp<Time3 & eventTimestamp>Time1)

      error1 = sum(videoActionsX_T1$type==" error ")
      pause1 = sum(videoActionsX_T1$type==" pause ")
      play1 = sum(videoActionsX_T1$type==" play ")
      ratechange1 = sum(videoActionsX_T1$type==" ratechange ")
      seeked1 = sum(videoActionsX_T1$type==" seeked ")
      stalled1 = sum(videoActionsX_T1$type==" stalled ")

      error2 = sum(videoActionsX_T2$type==" error ")
      pause2 = sum(videoActionsX_T2$type==" pause ")
      play2 = sum(videoActionsX_T2$type==" play ")
      ratechange2 = sum(videoActionsX_T2$type==" ratechange ")
      seeked2 = sum(videoActionsX_T2$type==" seeked ")
      stalled2 = sum(videoActionsX_T2$type==" stalled ")

      error3 = sum(videoActionsX_T3$type==" error ")
      pause3 = sum(videoActionsX_T3$type==" pause ")
      play3 = sum(videoActionsX_T3$type==" play ")
      ratechange3 = sum(videoActionsX_T3$type==" ratechange ")
      seeked3 = sum(videoActionsX_T3$type==" seeked ")
      stalled3 = sum(videoActionsX_T3$type==" stalled ")

      data<-data.frame(anon_ID=userX,
                       error1 = error1,
                       pause1 = pause1,
                       play1 = play1,
                       ratechange1 = ratechange1,
                       seeked1=seeked1,
                       stalled1=stalled1,
                       error2 = error2,
                       pause2 = pause2,
                       play2 = play2,
                       ratechange2 = ratechange2,
                       seeked2 =seeked2,
                       stalled2 = stalled2,
                       error3 = error3,
                       pause3 = pause3,
                       play3 = play3,
                       ratechange3 = ratechange3,
                       seeked3 = seeked3,
                       stalled3 = stalled3)
      return(data)
    }

    videoLectureActions<-structure(list(username = c("exampleID1", "exampleID1", "exampleID1", 
                                                     "exampleID2", "exampleID2", "exampleID2", "exampleID3", "exampleID3", 
                                                     "exampleID3", "exampleID3"), currentTime = c("103.701247", "103.701247", 
                                                                                                  "107.543877", "107.543877", "116.456507", "116.456507", "119.987188", 
                                                                                                  "177.816693", "183.417124", "183.417124"), playbackRate = c("null", 
                                                                                                                                                              "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", 
                                                                                                                                                              "null"), pause = c("true", "false", "true", "false", "true", 
                                                                                                                                                                                 "false", "true", "false", "true", "false"), error = c("null", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "null"), networkState = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "1", "1", "1"), readyState = c("4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "4", "4", "4", "4"), lectureID = c("exampleLectureID1", "exampleLectureID1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "exampleLectureID1", "exampleLectureID1", "exampleLectureID1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "exampleLectureID1", "exampleLectureID1", "exampleLectureID1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "exampleLectureID1", "exampleLectureID1"), eventTimestamp = c("2013-03-04 18:51:49", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2013-03-04 18:51:50", "2013-03-04 18:51:54", "2013-03-04 18:51:56", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2013-03-04 18:52:05", "2013-03-04 18:52:07", "2013-03-04 18:52:11", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2013-03-04 18:59:17", "2013-03-04 18:59:23", "2013-03-04 18:59:31"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ), initTimestamp = c("2013-03-04 18:44:15", "2013-03-04 18:44:15", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "2013-03-04 18:44:15", "2013-03-04 18:44:15", "2013-03-04 18:44:15", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "2013-03-04 18:44:15", "2013-03-04 18:44:15", "2013-03-04 18:44:15", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "2013-03-04 18:44:15", "2013-03-04 18:44:15"), type = c(" pause ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                " play ", " pause ", " play ", " pause ", " play ", " pause ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                " play ", " pause ", " play "), prevTime = c("103.701247 ", "103.701247 ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "107.543877 ", "107.543877 ", "116.456507 ", "116.456507 ", "119.987188 ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "177.816693 ", "183.417124 ", "183.417124 ")), .Names = c("username", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "currentTime", "playbackRate", "pause", "error", "networkState", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "readyState", "lectureID", "eventTimestamp", "initTimestamp", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "type", "prevTime"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 17L, 21L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          28L, 936L, 957L, 988L), class = "data.frame")
    data<-structure(list(anon_ID = c("exampleID1", "exampleID2", "exampleID3" ), maxGrade = c(10, 5, 10), firstGrade = c(10, 5, 8), lastGrade = c(10, 5, 10), total_submissions = c(1L, 1L, 3L), Time1 = structure(c(1361993741, 1362356090, 1362357401), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), TimeM = structure(c(1361993741, 1362356090, 1362492744), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), TimeL = structure(c(1361993741, 1362356090, 1362492744), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("anon_ID", "maxGrade", "firstGrade", "lastGrade", "total_submissions", "Time1", "TimeM", "TimeL"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

    library(foreach)
    library(doMC)
    registerDoMC(2)  #change the 2 to your number of CPU cores  

    n <- nrow(data)
    res <- list("vector", n)
    foreach(i=1:n, .verbose=FALSE, .combine=rbind) %do% {  
      res[[i]] <- with(data, DataVideoActionT(anon_ID[i], Time1[i], TimeM[i], TimeL[i]))
    }
    test<-do.call(rbind, res)
```

I have 3 questions.

1. How can I make foreach not print to the console? This is how it looks when I run it

   ```
   foreach(i=1:n, .verbose=FALSE, .combine=rbind) %do% {  
   +   res[[i]] <- with(data, DataVideoActionT(anon_ID[i], Time1[i], TimeM[i], TimeL[i]))
   + }
        anon_ID error1 pause1 play1 ratechange1 seeked1 stalled1
   1 exampleID1      0      0     0           0       0        0
   2 exampleID2      0      0     0           0       0        0
   3 exampleID3      0      0     0           0       0        0
     error2 pause2 play2 ratechange2 seeked2 stalled2 error3 pause3
   1      0      0     0           0       0        0      0      0
   2      0      0     0           0       0        0      0      0
   3      0      2     2           0       0        0      0      2
     play3 ratechange3 seeked3 stalled3
   1     0           0       0        0
   2     0           0       0        0
   3     2           0       0        0
   ```

I don't want that in the console with thousands of observations.

1. I want to run this in parallel, I i change the %do% for %dopar% the code stop working. Instead of getting test with 3 observations and 19 variables I get a 2x1 character matrix
2. Is there a better way of doing this? If so, could you explain why is better?

Thanks!

Comment: Add your code and an example of the dataset, e.g. `head( mydata )`. If your data has many many columns then consider making a toy example that adequately illustrates your problem. It is too much to guess the structure of your input data *and* what your function does. Please add it! :-)

Comment: Read `?lapply` and note the *See Also* section, which says, "...`mapply` for applying a function to *m*ultiple arguments."

Comment: Good edit. +1 for responding positively to the constructive criticism to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapply` is designed for your needs, as it will allow you to combine values per case, do computations and return a bigger matrix.

Note that I just took the arguments "user", "time1" and "time2" for a small example.

```
# This is a matrix of 3 columns
data <- replicate(3, 1:5)

# Your function takes some args, and returns extra info 

your_function <- function(user, time1, time2) {
  c(user, time1, time2, time1*time2, time1+time2, time1/time2)
}

# Here it comes together:
t(mapply(your_function, data[,1], data[,2], data[,3]))

# Output:
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#   [1,]    1    1    1    1    2    1
#   [2,]    2    2    2    4    4    1
#   [3,]    3    3    3    9    6    1
#   [4,]    4    4    4   16    8    1
#   [5,]    5    5    5   25   10    1
```

Confirm yourself that it works :)

As a bonus, I did the benchmark for your input and output, and the median time it takes based on 100 evaluations is **24 milliseconds**. Naturally, this depends what `your_function` actually does.

Code used:

```
data <- cbind(1:2000, replicate(18, rnorm(2000)))
f <- function(user, time1, time2, time3) {
  c(user, time1, time2, time3,
    time1+time2, time2+time3, time1+time3, time1+time2+time3,
    time1+time2, time2+time3, time1+time3, time1+time2+time3,
    time1+time2, time2+time3, time1+time3, time1+time2+time3,
    time1+time2, time2+time3, time1+time3)
}
result <- t(mapply(f, data[,1], data[,2], data[,3], data[,4]))  
result       # dim(result)   2000 by 19
```

### Edited to solve your specific situation (comments for clarifications):

Change

```
data<-data.frame(anon_ID=userX,
                 ...
                 ...
                 ...)
```

from your function with:

```
data<-c(error1, pause1, play1, ratechange1, seeked1, stalled1, error2, 
        pause2, play2, ratechange2, seeked2, stalled2, error3, pause3, 
        play3, ratechange3, seeked3, stalled3)
```

And then do the following:

```
test<-t(mapply(DataVideoActionT, userX=data$anon_ID, 
               Time1=data$Time1, Time2=data$TimeM, Time3=data$TimeL))

colnames(test) <- c("error1", "pause1", "play1", "ratechange1", "seeked1", 
                    "stalled1", "error2", "pause2", "play2", "ratechange2", 
                    "seeked2", "stalled2", "error3", "pause3", "play3", 
                    "ratechange3", "seeked3", "stalled3")

test
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a concern. The help says "... mapply applies FUN to the first elements of each ... argument, the second elements, the third elements, and so on. Arguments are recycled if necessary." I need to apply the function for user1, time1 of user 1, and so on. It would be wrong to apply the function to user 1 and time 1 of user 2. Does it make sense? Is there a way of doing what I want?

Comment: @Ignacio I am confused, sorry. Aren't user ID's not supposed to be mixed?

Comment: The recycling means that if your `data[,2]` (that is, time1) has 10 elements, and time2 has 20 elements, those time2 elements will indeed be recycled. If your data columns are all of equal length, nothing will be recycled.

Comment: Thanks! I just added code with an example. I think I'm almost there. I just have that new additional question of why is anon_ID always ==1 in my example

Comment: try using `test[,1]` to further inspect what this 1 is (actually 'factor, 1'). Upon closer inspection, you are left with a list, while you should have a matrix.

Comment: The problem is that you used data <- data.frame(). You are then left with a data.frame, which is more difficult for `mapply` to put together than if you'd replace it with `data <- c(userX, ....)`

Comment: If I were you I'd remove the userX as a column: this one is causing the resulting matrix to be `as.character`. Since you already have the row.names to be an identifier, you could simply omit this.

Comment: Thanks!. Can you take a look at the solution I'm proposing now? My head is more use to work with do loops. Please let me know if you think your solution is better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36628/discussion-between-ignacio-and-dualinity)

Answer (score 0):

You can use APPLY
Below you find example of code, that should help you!

```
dane_evaluations<-data.frame(dane_evaluations,time_spent=apply(dane_evaluations[,c('documentevaluation_start','documentevaluation_end')],1,function(x) time_spent(x[1], x[2])))
```

name of the function being applied: `time_spent`
and the function takes two arguments: `documentevaluation_start`, `documentevaluation_end` being columns of data frame `dane_evaluations`
as result of applying the data frame is extended by the column `time_spent` with appropriate value calculated by function for each row.

---

EXAMPLE DATA:

subseting data_frame:

```
head(dane_evaluations[,c('documentevaluation_start','documentevaluation_end')])
    documentevaluation_start     documentevaluation_end
1 2013-02-07 13:53:57.073760 2013-02-07 14:10:29.445997
2 2013-02-07 14:28:29.463068 2013-02-07 14:34:56.867517
```

applaying function:

```
time_spent <- function(from,to) {
op <- options(digits.secs = 3)  
 as.numeric((strptime(to, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")-strptime(from, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")),units="secs")
}
```

how it looks after applying function:

```
head(dane_evaluations[,c('documentevaluation_start','documentevaluation_end','time_spent')])
    documentevaluation_start     documentevaluation_end time_spent
1 2013-02-07 13:53:57.073760 2013-02-07 14:10:29.445997   992.3722
2 2013-02-07 14:28:29.463068 2013-02-07 14:34:56.867517   387.4044
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do.call` and `Vectorize`:

```
t(do.call(Vectorize(f), DF[,c("userX", "Time1", "Time2", "Time3")]))
```

where `f` is your function and `DF` your dataframe. You have to transpose in order to preserve the number of columns.